# creating array of data from laravel collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections

I have  a collection of project data from my mysql database, I have an array of months of the year, I wanting to move each project into the correct mmonth array based on the projects `created_at` attribute.

So far I have this,

```
$months = array();
$projects = $organisation->projects->filter(function($project){
    $months[date('n', strtotime($project->created_at)) - 1][] = $project;
});
```

I would have hoped that this would create something like,

```
0 => array(
    'Project 1',
    'Project 2,
    '...'
),
1 => array(),
2 => array(),
3 => array(),
4 => array(),
5 => array(), 
6 => array(),
7 => array(),
8 => array(),
9 => array(),
10 => array(),
11 => array()
```

So basically I wanting to filter through my collection and place projects that started in january into the first entry in an array, and projects that started in dec on the last month of array, but all I get return is empty array, if I return the projects collection, it is full of projects thoujgh.

Comment: Does that mean when you print out months below you get an empty array?

Comment: Are you sure `$organisation->projects`  this is returning collection to you ? - just a suggestion check once because code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code you have provided

```
$months = array();
$projects = $organisation->projects->filter(function($project){
    $months[date('n', strtotime($project->created_at)) - 1][] = $project;
});
```

is that the variable `$months` inside your anonymous function is different from external variable `$months`. This is why your anonymous function does nothing.

Please check the [documentation for anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be passed to the use language construct.

This is where PHP differs from JavaScript, for example. You need to declare external variables you are going to use in the closure to make them available.

Another important note is that you should inherit variable by reference `&$months`.

I think the code should be

```
$months = array();
$projects = $organisation->projects->filter(function($project) use (&$months) {
    $months[date('n', strtotime($project->created_at)) - 1][] = $project;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$months = array();
$projects = $organisation->projects->filter(function($project){
    $months[date('n', strtotime($project->created_at)) - 1][] = $project;
});
```

Instead of this try as below:

```
$months = array();
$projects = $organisation->projects->filter(function($project) use ($months){
    $months[date('n', strtotime($project->created_at)) - 1][] = $project;
});
```

As `$months` is external variable and you wanted to use in the inner function

Answer (score 0):

**This is example code can be help you.**

```
$projects = $organisation->projects->groupBy(function($project,$key){
     return date('n', strtotime($project->created_at));
});
```